# Does a font file has a seperate table for each character set?

Tags: windows, unicode, fonts, codepages

I am trying to understand what is contained in a font file without getting into too much details.

I have created a simple diagram to illustrate my understanding so far, the diagram contains a "glyph table" that encompasses the glyphs available for the font, and each glyph has an index to identify it.

There is also other tables for the character sets supported by the font, there is a Unicode table that will map each Unicode code point to its corresponding glyph, and there is a number of other tables for the supported ANSI code pages.

Now when a program is reading a Unicode text, the program (or Windows that is) will acquire the glyph for each Unicode code point from the Unicode table and displays it.
When the program is reading an ANSI text, the program will acquire the glyph for each character code from one of the ANSI tables (depending on the selected ANSI code page in Windows) and displays it.

This is the diagram:

[image]

Is my understanding accurate?

Comment: Every code page character should map somewhere into Unicode, so there's no *need* for separate tables. I don't know enough about font files to know if they contain redundant tables though.

Answer (score 1):

OpenType fonts *may* contain separate mapping tables (actually: subtables of the [cmap table](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/cmap.htm)), but for most relatively modern cases, the division into codepages/character sets under Windows is performed by Windows itself (through the Unicode cmap subtable).